# Is a male and female Type-C port interchangeable on a device?

Tags: usb, usb-c

This is my first time using USB-C. I am implementing a reference schematic for a school project, however it uses a male Type-C connector. I would like to use a female Type-C socket instead and use a cable to connect my device to a host.

Is a female socket a drop-in replacement in my case? My main concern is that some Type-C cables are said to be active and I might mess up.

The USB schematic is below:
[image]

And for reference, this is what the device (LAN7800 EV board) looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not.

On further research, one needs a *mux* in order to accommodate all the possible configurations of a Type-C to Type-C connection among other things.

Any device implementing a Type-C receptacle *must* have a mux [[1]](https://www.ti.com/lit/wp/slyy109b/slyy109b.pdf).

A reference implementation is the [TIDA-00890](https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-00890) from Texas Intruments.

Answer (score 2):

Changing a plug to a socket is never a drop-in replacement. And it's not even about having an active or passive cable, it won't be compatible due to how all USB cables are wired.

USB plug to plug cables are not wired straight thru, and devices with a socket are responsible for detecting cable orientation and connecting to the right pins depending on which way the cable is plugged in.

Thus just replacing a plug with a socket will not work unless the pins are routed to match how an USB cable is wired, and even then, without cable orientation detection and muxing to correct pins, it will only work when cable is plugged in to your device in one orientation. Which is not how a real Type C device should work.